# Change background color of UI elements in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide

I am using Eclipse 3.5 IDE on Fedora linux. Too much white or light gray color is hurtful to my eyes. I managed to change the background of editor and console window to black but nothing else so I am still seeing 30 to 40% space as not black. How do I change the background color of package explorer?

If not possible then how to hack into eclipse source code or config files somewhere to do that and also to change all UI panels color to black from the current light grey and text to some other color from black?

Comment: Did you already try using the linux desktop configuration, to set background colors globally for all applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of the appearance of Eclipse is controlled by the GTK+ theme. You can edit the current theme or try different themes out.  The "Nokoka-Midnight" theme, for instance, is almost entirely black.  I like a program called gtk-chtheme to switch them.

Nokoka-Midnight
[image]

Comment: It turned to be much simpler. Simply go to System | Preferences | Appearance. More are available at: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_Customizing_Fedora_Desktop_Themes

Comment: @Alan, cool.  That is essentially the same thing (changing your GTK+ theme).  Works since you are running Gnome which is built on top of GTK.  Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

To change only editor without affecting the entire IDE you can try two approaches:

1. http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/
2. **Go to Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors** and **Java>Editor>Syntax Colouring** and edit the colors there.