# Eclipse IDE - Background color

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, epic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change background color of UI elements in eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834065/change-background-color-of-ui-elements-in-eclipse-ide)

As you all probably know, the default is plain white or should I say, glowing-eye-killer-white.

I'm looking for a color scheme to make it more eye friendly, does anyone know one? (Yes tried Google and found some Java schema's which didn't go well with Perl / EPIC).

Thanks,

Comment: maybe its over ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834065/change-background-color-of-ui-elements-in-eclipse-ide and others

Comment: I dont want to change my whole Linux theme only for Eclipse... that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have a look at this eclipse plugin http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme. I think the color scheme is mostly for editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/
Many themes are available there and a video tutorial to show how to import the file at
http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

After adding the eclipse color themes addon as listed above it automatically adds a number of themes.You can just select the color theme from the preferences.

```
Menu->Window->Preferences

General->Appearance->Color Theme
```