# How to change the color of UI elements in eclipse IDE on Linux OS?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I saw the following post located here:

[Change background color of UI elements in eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834065/change-background-color-of-ui-elements-in-eclipse-ide)

But still unsure of how to do this in Linux.  Are there .prefs files that need to be edited?  I am on KDE would I still be able to use gtk-chtheme?  If yes, how?  Or is there an alternative way to get the UI to appear as it is displayed in the link above?  Is there a step-by-step process?

I am using eclipse 3.6.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try install Aptana Studio 3 (as a plugin) and use all the theming features it has.
Check out thispost http://danielsmedegaardbuus.dk/2011-04-16/fixing-console-and-other-colors-in-aptana-studio-3/
It won't be exactly as it appears at the link above, but very close.

Cheers,
Max